# Android notification - show the small icon only in the notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to show a local notification with a large icon and text, but use the small icon only in the notification bar.

Is that possible?

More Details:

[image]

in the picture you can see that some of the notifications have two icons (large and small) and some have only one (only large).

I want to have only the largeIcon but I need to show the smallIcon inside the notification bar (top bar).

Comment: can you more explain your problem ?

Comment: I think you would have to use a custom RemoteViews.